# Wesite not updating realtime on vps

Tags: codeigniter, vps

i have problem, my website is not updating realtime when i updating the script view (html) in this case using CI
it will take about 15 - 30 minutes to update
already try to clear cache on client browser, not working

thanks

Comment: can you open it in chrome/firefox/egde, press F12, disable cache and then try the same?

Comment: yes have to try it, but not works